# pdf of a particular distribution

Tags: matlab, statistics, probability

I am new to Matlab. I would like to check the so call "logarithmic law" for determinant of random matrices with Matlab, but still do not know how.

Logarithmic law:

Let A be a random Bernoulli matrix (entries are iid, taking value +-1 with prob. 1/2) of size n by n. We may want to compare the probability density function of (log(det(A^2))-log(factorial(n-1)))/sqrt(2n) with the pdf of Gaussian distribution. The logarithmic law says that the pdf of the first will approach to that of the second when n approaches infinity.

My Matlab task is very simple: check the comparison for, say n=100. Anyone knows how to do so?

Thanks.

Comment: [pdf](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/toolbox/stats/pdf.html) is here in Matlab docs.

Comment: @H.H.: I did a quick a search on google for "Logarithmic Law for Random Determinants" and found [two](http://books.google.com/books?id=fsMamZXZwIsC&pg=PA60) [book references](http://books.google.com/books?id=LeGMfJwUK3cC&pg=PA47).. I think the last term should be: `sqrt(2*log(n))`

Answer (score 5):

Consider the following experiment:

```
n = 100;                           %# matrix size
num = 1000;                        %# number of matrices to generate

detA2ln = zeros(num,1);
for i=1:num
    A = randi([0 1],[n n])*2 - 1;  %# -1,+1
    detA2ln(i) = log(det(A^2));
end

%# `gammaln(n)` is more accurate than `log(factorial(n-1))`
myPDF = ( detA2ln - gammaln(n) ) ./ sqrt(2*log(n));
normplot(myPDF)
```

[image]

Note that for large matrices, the determinant of A*A will be too large to represent in double numbers and will return `Inf`. However we only require the log of the determinant, and there exist other approachs to find this result that keeps the computation in log-scale.

In the comments, @yoda suggested using the eigenvalues `detA2(i) = real(sum(log(eig(A^2))));`, I also found a [submission](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22026-safe-computation-of-logarithm-determinat-of-large-matrix) on FEX that have a similar implementation (using LU or Cholesky decomposition)

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works for me. (btw, there was a typo in my formula, the denominator should be sqrt(2*log(n)).

Comment: Also, is there anyway to check for matrices of larger size? My Matlab works for n=100, but not for n=200, and how about n=1000? The comparison for n=100 seems still unconvincing.

Comment: @H.H. Replace the last line in the `for` loop with this: `detA2(i) = real(sum(log(eig(A^2))));` This will be slower, but will let you run it for matrices as large as your system/MATLAB will allow.

Comment: @yoda: thanks I added a note how to safely compute the log of the determinant as you suggested